# Making Members Public Vs Making Members Friend and Using The InternalsVisibleTo Attribute

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was wondering if exposing the 'interface' members of my types as `Public` is the correct thing to do?
What made me wonder is `Public` members can be invoked by other assemblies, could they then be invoked by another application that I never intended to interact with mine?
I'm guessing this isn't possible as how would you make an application secure in that scenario?
So my question is should I keep making my members `Public` or should I make them `Friend` and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to expose them to other assemblies within my application?

For the stuff I write it doesn't matter I'm just asking from a learning/interest perspective.

Comment: What distinguishes other assemblies within your application from a theoretical third-party client?

Comment: @Craig If I make my members Public then nothing (as I understand it), whether it's my app or a third-party it's the same. If I instead make my members Friend and use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute then my assembly 'grants permission' to what external assemblies can invoke it's Friend members giving some protection from a third party. Is my thinking right and would you bother?

Comment: I'm intending this more as a design question: if there is something "special" about the other assemblies in your application (aside from them being yours, rather than third party) that distinguishes them and argues for something different access.  Keep in mind that "protection" is a limited benefit since a hostile third party can always get to private methods using reflection.

Comment: @Craig Ah... I see what you were asking me now. No nothing special about them so no requirment for special access so I need to just leave them Public. Thanks heaps Craig.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you've already read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels).  Does a fair job of explaining it all in my mind at least.

General rule you should ideally use the most restrictive access level possible for your use case.